# How to use AJAX call to refresh img src

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, image, xmlhttprequest

I have a PHP script *picQuery.php* which returns the path to a picture.  I have another script which calls the picQuery.php and should then display the picture, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

The code I have displays the file path in picFrame. What I want is something like the following line which I have commented out as it doesn't work.  How should it be written?

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action=""> 
<button type="button" onclick="getPic(this.value)">Click Me!</button>
</form>
<p id="picFrame"</p>

<!--<img src=<p id="picFrame"</p>  alt="text"  style="width:304px;height:228px;">-->

<script>
function getPic() {
  var xhttp;
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("picFrame").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      alert('response = '.this.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "picQuery.php?q=4", true);
  xhttp.send();   
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### picQuery.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body> <?php echo "PIC1.jpg" ?> </body> </html>
```

Comment: You can replace the image element with an 'Image' in JS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image

And please, edit your code, you have a typo.

Comment: @bobo_dev - I have been studying the reference you gave but cannot figure out how to get it to display a picture.  Could you be a bit more specific please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways this could be achieved.

The simplest might be to create an instance of [Image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image), assign the responseText to the [*src*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-src) property of the image, set the [style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) property accordingly, and then set the innerHTML of the element with **id** value *picFrame* to the [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) of the image.

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src= this.responseText;
        image.style = "width:304px;height:228px;";
        document.getElementById("picFrame").innerHTML = image.outerHTML;
    }
}
```

See it demonstrated in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/im1c-qw8g).

Otherwise the `<img>` tag that is currently commented out could be used if the *id* attribute was changed or if it was accessed via the DOM as a child of the paragraph element. Though if the initial value of the *src* property is empty or an invalid URL for an image, then the browser might display a broken image icon.

So the image could be updated like this:

```
<p id="picFrame">
    <img alt="text" id="picFrameImg" style="width:304px;height:228px;" />
</p>
```

And then accessed via Javascript:

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById('picFrameImg').src = this.responseText;
}
```

See a demonstration of this below. Hopefully the AJAX still works in the long term, though it might not, given the phpfiddle code files. If it stops working, [this plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/rtFLw2Q8WaLRON6Eh1LO/) might be a good demonstration but bear in mind that *picQuery.php* is *NOT* being executed as a regular PHP file.

```js
function getPic() {
  var xhttp;
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("picFrameImg").src = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://main.xfiddle.com/code_65644594.php?q=4", true);
  xhttp.send();   
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <button type="button" onclick="getPic(this.value)">Click Me!</button>
</form>
<p id="picFrame">
  <img alt="text" id="picFrameImg" style="width:304px;height:228px;" src="" />
</p>
```

#### UPDATE 4/21/2017

The PHP code provided will not work with the AJAX approach. It should return the path of the image **without** the html tags around it.

So update the PHP from:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body> <?php echo "PIC1.jpg" ?> </body> </html>
```

To this:

```
<?php echo "PIC1.jpg"; ?>
```

That way, the AJAX code will essentially be updating the image tag from

```
<img alt="text" id="picFrameImg" style="width:304px;height:228px;" />
```

to this:

```
<img alt="text" id="picFrameImg" style="width:304px;height:228px;" src="PIC1.jpg" />
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply Sam.  If I run the code in your example at the end it works, but this is just displaying the image "https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWMDr.jpg?s=32&g=1".  When I try to include the AJAX call to get the image path from my picQuery.php it doesn't work.  You say 'AJAX removed, since there would be issues with CORS' does this mean that I cannot use AJAX to get the image path, or am I missing something here?

Comment: @MickSulley I updated the last snippet after updating the headers to hopefully avoid the CORS issue but like I mentioned in the text, that might not work long-term. I also provided a [plunker example](http://embed.plnkr.co/rtFLw2Q8WaLRON6Eh1LO/) but realize that the *picQuery.php* is not really being executed as a PHP file

Comment: Again if I try your code it works to display my profile picture, but if I change the line
xhttp.open("GET", "http://main.xfiddle.com/code_65644594.php?q=4", true);
to
xhttp.open("GET", "picQuery.php?q=4", true);
It does not work.  Opening web console I get a 404 message
http://localhost/www/SlidesDevel/%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Chtml%3E%3Chead%3Ein%20picQuery.php/2015/PIC20151107T140312.JPG%3C/head%3E%3Cbody%3E%3C/body%3E%3C/html%3E
Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: @MickSulley it appears your last comment was incomplete - can you let me know what you are trying to communicate? I presume it is something about the image (string) returned by _picQuery.php_...

Comment: Yes if I change it to xhttp.open("GET", "picQuery.php?q=4", true);   it does not work, in web console it displays a 404 message GET http://localhost/www/SlidesDevel/%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Chtml%3E%3Chead%3Ein%20picQuery.php/2015/PIC20151107T140312.JPG%3C/head%3E%3Cbody%3E%3C/body%3E%3C/html%3E [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]

Comment: You need to provide the correct path - e.g. if *picQuery.php* is at the root of the webserver, then you could use */picQuery.php*...otherwise without the slash it will be **relative** to whatever path the script is in (e.g. /www/slidesDevel/page.html then it would look for /www/slidesDevel/picQuery.php). Does that make sense?

Comment: I have been doing some more investigation but still can't fix it.  picQuery is in the same directory so that is not the issue.  If I create another paragraph id which is text and get the AJAX call to update that, it displays the file path as expected.  If I cut and paste that into the img src in code and run it, it displays the picture as expected.  If I then click the button, which should update with the same path data, it displays the default text, so presumably the img src is no longer valid.  So it seems that the problem is in the way I am updating img src, but I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Hmm - would it be helpful to compare with this page I just uploaded to [this test site](http://samonela.scienceontheweb.net/PHP/msPage.html)... see the results of my network inspection in Firefox [here](http://imgur.com/a/KW2L8)

Comment: I have just changed my picQuery.php so it just returns 'PIC1.jpg', copied your code to sam.php, all 3 files are in the webserver root and I still get the same.  http://localhost/%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Chtml%3E%3Chead%3EPIC1.jpg%3C/head%3E%3Cbody%3E%3C/body%3E%3C/html%3E   Does it work for you if you do that?

Comment: Ah - it appears that string you pasted (_localhost/%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Chtml%3E%3Chead%3EPIC1.jpg%3C/_) is an url-encoded form of `localhost/<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>PIC1.jpg</` (at least that is what is returned from [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent). So it appears your php script is echoing the starting HTML tags... try to make it only echo the file name. See the [updated demo page](http://samonela.scienceontheweb.net/PHP/msPage.html) where the image is in the same directory & the PHP page uses it

Comment: My php just returns PIC1.jpg when I run it.  If I add a text id to the main page and update that it is PIC1.jpg, but when it updates as img src it doesn't work.  Have you run this locally? Does it work for you?

Comment: are you able to add your PHP code to your question? That might be the most helpful here. I haven't run it locally but I am pretty sure that it would yield the same results as the demo page...

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo "PIC1.jpg"
?>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142338/discussion-between-mick-sulley-and-sam-onela).